# ChartJS doughnut legend click

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a problem with custom onClick function on doughnut chart.
The only thing I need is to override default legend onClick function calling the original one + my custom code.
Following their official documentation and this suggestion on [github](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5104#issuecomment-355491727) page I wrote this js

```
var defaultLegendClickHandler = Chart.defaults.doughnut.legend.onClick;

var newLegendClickHandler = function (e, legendItem) {
    console.log(legendItem);
    defaultLegendClickHandler.call(this, e, legendItem);

};
```

Then I associate it to the onClick option ([JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jes5321f/1/)) but it is not working. It seems that the `legendItem` variable is always an empty array so the default click function does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSfiddle looks fine except that the `newLegendClickHandler` is defined at the wrong place inside `options`. You should define it inside `legend` as follows.

```
legend: {
  position: 'top',
  onClick: newLegendClickHandler
},
```

> Please also check [Custom On Click Actions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#custom-on-click-actions) from Chart.js
>   documentation

Comment: ...this is embarassing...I tried for about an hour to find the problem and it was only a wrong definition positioning. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The click handler was set to the chart itself and not the legend. Move the new onClick handler inside of the legend options.

```
var options = {
    cutoutPercentage: 20,
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    onClick: newLegendClickHandler,
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Chart.js Doughnut Chart'
  },
  animation: {
    animateScale: true,
    animateRotate: true
  }
};
```